# Java while loop not limiting scope?

Tags: java, gwt, loops, while-loop

Working on a side project, trying to iterate through a flex table and pull data. The table has a column with another table in it that spans the rows of the rows it is associated with. I grab that data first and then get the rows associated with it, populate it into an assembly and and then store it in an arraylist. My problem is while it pulls data correctly, it is not storing into the arraylist. It overwrites all the previous lines and I can't figure out why. Is this a scope issue with while loops? Am I not declaring something correctly? Code is below

```
private static void submitOrder() {

    if (nullCheck()) {
        ArrayList<AssemblyLine> assemblyLines = new ArrayList<AssemblyLine>();
        HorizontalPanel hPanel = (HorizontalPanel) fTable.getWidget(fTable.getRowCount() - 1, 0);
        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) hPanel.getWidget(0);
        int rowSpan = 0;
        int currentRow = 1;
        int currentAssemblyLineRow = 1;

        while (currentRow < fTable.getRowCount() - 2) {
            // get current info table and set initial data
            FlexTable currentInfoTable = (FlexTable) fTable.getWidget(currentRow, 7);
            rowSpan = fTable.getFlexCellFormatter().getRowSpan(currentRow, 7);
            AssemblyLine al = new AssemblyLine();
            ListBox assembler = (ListBox) currentInfoTable.getWidget(2, 1);
            DateBox date = (DateBox) currentInfoTable.getWidget(3, 1);
            al.setAssemblerName(assembler.getValue(assembler.getSelectedIndex()));
            al.setDate(date.getValue());
            al.setAssemblyID(Integer.parseInt(fTable.getHTML(currentRow, 0)));

            // if "use all info for lots" is checked set assembler and date
            // to that
//other data set here

            // iterate through related rows and store assemblylines in
            // database, I think the error is in here
            while (currentAssemblyLineRow < (rowSpan + currentRow)) {
                al.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(fTable.getHTML(currentAssemblyLineRow, 5)));
                System.out.println("al.getQuantity: " + al.getQuantity());
                ListBox lb = (ListBox) fTable.getWidget(currentAssemblyLineRow, 6);
                al.setPartLotNumber(lb.getItemText(lb.getSelectedIndex()));
                System.out.println("al.getPartLotNumber: " + al.getPartLotNumber());
                assemblyLines.add(al);
                System.out.println("al.tostring: " + al.toString());
                System.out.println("a.tostring: " + assemblyLines.get(assemblyLines.size() - 1).toString());
                currentAssemblyLineRow++;
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < assemblyLines.size(); k++) {
                System.out.println("a.tostring: " + k + " " + assemblyLines.get(k).toString());
            }

            // then iterate to next infotable
            currentRow = currentRow + rowSpan;

        }

        DatabaseUtils.submitAssemblyLines(assemblyLines);
    } else {
        Window.alert("Oops! please fill out all boxes!");
    }

}
```

here is the output from console

```
    al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: 43528
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=43528, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=43528, quantity=1]
al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: H17253
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=H17253, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=H17253, quantity=1]
al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: 31561414
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=31561414, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=31561414, quantity=1]
al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: 001122
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=001122, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=001122, quantity=1]
al.getQuantity: 2
al.getPartLotNumber: 123456
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=123456, quantity=2]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=123456, quantity=2]
al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: 103534
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=103534, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=103534, quantity=1]
al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: P12345
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 0 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 1 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 2 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 3 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 4 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 5 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 6 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: H17253
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=H17253, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=H17253, quantity=1]
al.getQuantity: 2
al.getPartLotNumber: 001122
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=001122, quantity=2]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=001122, quantity=2]
al.getQuantity: 1
al.getPartLotNumber: P12345
al.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 0 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 1 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 2 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 3 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 4 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 5 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 6 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 7 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 8 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
a.tostring: 9 AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=0, AssemblyLotNumber=0, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=0, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLot at 0: Assembly [assemblyLotNumber=1, assemblyID=12, name=null, partID=null, quantities=null]
AssemblyLot at 1: Assembly [assemblyLotNumber=2, assemblyID=13, name=null, partID=null, quantities=null]
AssemblyLines at 0: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=7, AssemblyLotNumber=1, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=1, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 1: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=7, AssemblyLotNumber=1, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=1, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 2: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=7, AssemblyLotNumber=1, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=1, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 3: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=7, AssemblyLotNumber=1, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=1, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 4: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=7, AssemblyLotNumber=1, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=1, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 5: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=7, AssemblyLotNumber=1, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=1, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 6: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=7, AssemblyLotNumber=1, AssemblyID=12, AssemblerID=1, AssemblerName=John, date=Thu Aug 01 14:54:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 7: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=10, AssemblyLotNumber=2, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=2, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 8: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=10, AssemblyLotNumber=2, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=2, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
AssemblyLines at 9: AssemblyLine [AssemblyLineID=10, AssemblyLotNumber=2, AssemblyID=13, AssemblerID=2, AssemblerName=Blake, date=Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 PDT 2013, partLotNumber=P12345, quantity=1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate a new `AssemblyLine` each time through the loop. Right now, all you're doing is adding the same object over and over again (modifying it each time through the loop).

```
ListBox assembler = (ListBox) currentInfoTable.getWidget(2, 1);
DateBox date = (DateBox) currentInfoTable.getWidget(3, 1);

while (currentAssemblyLineRow < (rowSpan + currentRow)) {
    AssemblyLine al = new AssemblyLine();
    al.setAssemblerName(assembler.getValue(assembler.getSelectedIndex()));
    al.setDate(date.getValue());
    al.setAssemblyID(Integer.parseInt(fTable.getHTML(currentRow, 0)));
    // rest of loop body goes here (current code)
}
```

Comment: aren't I doing that already? the assemblyline is declared in the while loop, so doesn't that limit its scope to the one loop and then it is gone?

Comment: @john - You need to declare a new `AssemblyLine` inside the inner `while` loop. You're only declaring one each time through the outer `while` loop.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond, I was implementing what you said, it works! thank you very much Ted!